# Insert Lists into ttk Treeview Table

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am using `ttk.Treeview` to display a list of items and specific specifications about each item. I'm not entirely familiar with the function of the arguments in the `.insert()` method, and how I could use them to sort this list. The variable `self.active_list` is a list of items, where the items are lists which contain it's respective attributes.

```
def make_table(self):
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.master)
        
        self.tree.config(columns=("itm_id", "itm_name", "qty"))
        self.tree.column("itm_id", width=150)
        self.tree.heading("itm_id", text="Item ID")
        self.tree.column("itm_name", width=150)
        self.tree.heading("itm_name", text="Item Name")
        self.tree.column("qty", width=150)
        self.tree.heading("qty", text="Quantity")
        
        for i in range(len(self.active_list)):
            for j in range(len(self.active_list[0])):
                self.tree.insert("", i, text=self.active_list[i][j])
                    
        self.tree.place(x=0, y=0)
```

`self.active_list` holds the values below:

`[['8133324', 'resistor', '7'], ['2580453', 'arduino', '3'], ['8490385', 'jumper wire', '12']]`

The screenshot is how the Treeview looks when it is placed on the window. Obviously the quantities are not in the correct order, or the correct column. How can I better iterate through the list (line 12) and place all of the variables in the correct position? Thanks

[image: Table display from code above]

Comment: The `for j` loop is not necessary.